# How to convert a List<Object[]> to Stream<Object>

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-stream

I have a native query which returns a `List<Object[]>`.
I want to convert this `List` to a `Stream<Object>`. 
These Objects are different columns from different tables of my database.

What is the best solution to do that?

Create a DTO and convert a `List<DTO>` to `Stream<DTO>`? How can I do that?

Comment: I think you should really clarify your question. The two answers you got do something different? You cant say that the solution by J-Alex is working, and also accept something that does actually something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
List<Object[]> objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
Stream<Object> objectStream = objectsList.stream()
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream);
```

Comment: Initially I also thought that's what the OP wanted, but after reading the question again, I thought the OP wanted to create an instance of some class from each array.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming your `DTO` class has a proper constructor, you can write something like this:

```
List<Object[]> input = ...
Stream<DTO> dtos = input.stream().map(arr -> new DTO(arr[0], arr[1], ... , arr[n]);
```

Comment: To be honest, I understood the question from your answer.

Comment: I still don't get. And I am kinda wondering: that assumes that all arrays have the same number of elements?

Comment: @GhostCat that's what I was assuming.

Comment: It's giving stream of DTO and not Stream<Object> where Object is the each object in each array in list which Op is asking for. Though your solution is also good given we need an intermediate object to carry these objects.

Comment: I agree with @J-Alex